# Synchronization of data in multiple-core environment (Java-based)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition, multiprocessor

this is my first question ever so please be gentle on me.

What happens when two threads, say t1 and t2, running on separate CPU cores invoke a synchronized method on a shared object AT THE SAME TIME, i.e. in the same nanosecond/processor cycle? How and by what element of the architecture is the lock resolved?

It may seem like an obvious question but i could not find anything on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: google "how is java synchronized implemented"

Comment: One way is with atomic instructions.

Comment: only one thread will lock on object in case of `synchronized` method. you can not precisely say which one. it is decided by the jvm. other thread will wait for its turn until the lock is released by the first thread.

Comment: Imagine a toilet queue, half time at the Super Bowl. Lots of people, everyone wants the same thing. Guy A is next line and goes in. Guy B tries to cut the line and get in ahead of time. `synchronized` is Big Tough Guy, who tells Guy B to back the f off and wait in line until Guy A is done. And that is multithreading.

Comment: @flavian nice analogy.

Comment: There is an excellent book on Conurrency http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec simply says the synchronized method may only be entered by one thread at a time.  What architecture mechanism is used would depend on the JVM.

In the case of Oracle HotSpot (the JVM that almost everyone runs): the C++ code is GNU, and probably holds the answer for you.

But if you just need the assurance that it "just works", the specification gives that to you.

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

These days this is actually realized in hardware, so the processor has a special instruction to grant one thread out of many access. This has evolved from a pure software-based solution from last century, and the state of the art these days is what the AtomicInteger represents: a single, mutable integer, that is guaranteed to be thread-safe but never blocks.

Example: The [Intel Haswell Architecture](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/02/07/transactional-synchronization-in-haswell).